# performSegue on successful login - Firebase/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

What I want to do is segue to the appropriate view controller upon successful authentication with Firebase. So that when the user clicks "Sign In" it checks to see if the credentials are correct and then if they are it will segue to my next view controller. This is what I have and I keep getting error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Here is my viewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn


class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtAuthStatus: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

    if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        self.txtAuthStatus.text = "Signed in as " + user.email!;
    }
    else {
        self.txtAuthStatus.text = "";
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
    }

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let authentication = user.authentication
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!, accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)

    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            return
        }
        print("User logged in with Google")
    })
}




@IBAction func btnCreateUser(_ sender: Any) {
    if let email:String = txtEmail.text, let pass:String = txtPassword.text {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass) {
            (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code);
                if (errCode == .emailAlreadyInUse) {
                    self.txtAuthStatus.text = "Error: user already exists";
                } else {

                    self.txtAuthStatus.text = error.localizedDescription;
                }
            }
            if let user = user {
                self.txtAuthStatus.text = "Signed in as " + user.email!
                self.txtEmail.text = nil;
                self.txtPassword.text = nil;

            }
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func btnSignIn(_ sender: Any) {
    if let email:String = txtEmail.text, let pass:String = txtPassword.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass) {
            (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code);
                if (errCode == .userNotFound) {
                    self.txtAuthStatus.text = "Error: user not found";
                }
                else if (errCode == .wrongPassword) {
                    self.txtAuthStatus.text = "Error: wrong password";
                }
                else if (errCode == .userDisabled) {
                    self.txtAuthStatus.text = "Error: user account disabled";
                }
                else {
                    self.txtAuthStatus.text = error.localizedDescription;
                }
            }
            if let user = user {
                self.txtAuthStatus.text = "Signed in as " + user.email!
                self.txtEmail.text = nil;
                self.txtPassword.text = nil;
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signin", sender: self)

            }
        }
    }
}
@IBAction func btnSignOut(_ sender: Any) {
    try! Auth.auth().signOut();
    self.txtAuthStatus.text = "Signed out";
}

}
```

and here is my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: [:])
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                             annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

I have a segue between the view controller's I want to move between and the identifier for it is "signin"

Comment: So what's the *specific* issue we can duplicate? Thanks for the code dump, but how does that help *us* to help you? Are you having debug issues? Is the issue related to segueing? (That's in your title so I'm guessing so. But it seems like it may be from several places. So *why* do you believe it's from that? Please, specifics matter!)

Comment: Yes the issue is related to segueing and crashing the program when I try to call the self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signin", sender: self). The login itself works fine, and so does the rest of the app. I just need to solve a way that will allow me to segue after authentication via Firebase. My current solution causes  "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping" error. In the viewDidLoad, at the line with self.txtAuthStatus.text = "Signed in as " + user.email!;

Comment: Then you need to figure out what's `nil`! Possibly that either the use *has* no email or that your Friebase call isn't properly returning it? Again, thanks for the code dump, but this isn't a site to fix your code. There are literally *dozens* of questions related to finding nil when unwrapping. My first thoughts - okay second because I already gave you one place to check - is to check *all* your unwrapping code, **specifically** the line that gives you the `nil` error, find what *is* nil and fix it. (Not trying to be harsh, but this is a poor quality question.)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in that when I pushed to the next view controller it no longer had the text fields for email and password. By switching out the login function to a different .swift file and its view controller to a different class it no longer looked for those on loading and now it works flawlessly!